# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution

Tags: math, normal-distribution

I have downloaded the apache match package to my machine and compiled the code below without error, but when I run the class I got the error "ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution"

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution;

public class CumulativeProbability {
    private static NormalDistribution nd;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        nd = new NormalDistribution(100.30 , 232.45);
        System.out.println(nd.cumulativeProbability(3000));
        
        nd = new NormalDistribution(50.3, 10.1);
        System.out.println(nd.inverseCumulativeProbability(0.7));
    }
}
```

The error message:

C:\Distnormal>java CumulativeProbability
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/NormalDistribution
at CumulativeProbability.main(CumulativeProbability.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution

Trying with the command:
C:\Distnormal>java -cp "C:\Distnormal\commons-math3-3.6.1.jar" CumulativeProbability
Error: Could not find or load main class CumulativeProbability

below how I'm compiling:
C:\Distnormal>javac -cp "C:\Distnormal\commons-math3-3.6.1.jar" CumulativeProbability.java

I double-checked everything but could not find where the error is.

I already double-checked the source code, the jar file but not able to fix the error.

Comment: One thing to look at: verify that NormalDistribution in the jar file. Try `jar tvf yourjarfilename.jar` and then see if NormalDistribution is there, with *exactly* the same list of package qualifiers (org/apache/commons/math3/distribution in this case). If NormalDistribution is there, look at your classpath and verify the jar file is there, with the correct filesystem path.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your comment.
I run the jar tvf and saw the class file in there, also copy all file in the same folder, .java, .jar and compile again but still the same error

javac -cp "C:\Distnormal\commons-math3-3.6.1.jar" CumulativeProbability.java

I downloaded the jar file again but again the same classnotfound error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your main program and I can compile it and run it successfully with commons-math3-3.6.1.jar. I'm working on Ubuntu Linux.

Compile:

```
$ javac -d . -cp commons-math3-3.6.1/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar CumulativeProbability.java
```

The `-d .` means for javac to write .class files into `.` (i.e., current working directory).

Run:

```
$ java -cp commons-math3-3.6.1/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar:. CumulativeProbability
1.0
55.5964451783512
```

Note that I put `.` on the classpath, otherwise `java` doesn't find CumulativeProbability.

I think it must be a problem with the `-cp` option for you. Try this: write the path as either "C:\Distnormal\commons-math3-3.6.1.jar" (i.e. with two backslash characters) *or* "C:/Distnormal/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar" (i.e. with one forward slash character).

Comment: It worked!!! :) 
It was the -cp parameter, below how I solved in Windows following your tips

C:\Distnormal>java -cp "C:/Distnormal/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar;C:/Distnormal" CumulativeProbability
1.0
55.5964451783512

As you, I added the local path to find the .class file.

Thanks a lot Robert.